# How to define Eclipse external null annotations for parameters in JRE methods

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, nullable, external-annotations

I am trying to annotate the JRE method `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` from `java.util.Set` using Eclipse's [external null annotations](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_external_null_annotations.htm?cp=1_3_9_2). The expected effect should be equivalent to this:

```
 public interface Set<E> extends Collection<E> {
     ...
     <T> T @NonNull[] toArray(T @NonNull[] a);
     ...
 }
```

When using Eclipse's Annotate command I can annotate the return type of the method properly (after I selected the `T[]` and position the cursor before the `[`). However trying to do the same with the parameter fails. Pressing Cmd-1 simply beeps, as does selecting "Annotate" when calling the command from the context menu.

I finally ended up editing the corresponding `Set.eea` file manually to defined the required annotation, taking care of the proper [eea file layout](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis/External_Annotations#File_layout). I.e. I changed the annotatedSignature in:

```
class java/util/Set
toArray
 <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>([TT;)[TT;
 <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>([TT;)[1TT;
```

to

```
 <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>([1TT;)[1TT;
```

This works fine and the annotation is correctly processed by the compiler.

As I can annotate the return type but not a parameter type I am wondering what I am doing wrong. Or is this a limitation of the current Eclipse version?

*I am using Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0, Build id: 20150621-1200)
 and jdk1.8.0_60.*

Comment: Somewhat offtopic: Is there a pre-compiled collection of these external annotations? Or are you maintaining your own collection?

Comment: @HRJ I am maintaining my own collection of external annotation files. However I am planning to make them "open source" and publish them soon (via GitHub). I will leave a note here when this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>This is a bug indeed, I just filed https://bugs.eclipse.org/477461 to track this.</strike>

This was [bug 464081](https://bugs.eclipse.org/464081) which got fixed for 4.6 M1 (i.e., is available in current builds towards Eclipse Neon) and is currently proposed for 4.5.2 (Mars.2)